# sqlalchemy unicode issue

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Hi I am dvelopping an application in python with sqlalchemy and  mysql 5.1.58-1ubuntu1, I can get data from db without problem, except that I can not read not ascii characters like è, ò or the euro symbol, instead of the euro  I get
    \u20ac
this is how I create the engine for mysqlalchemy

```
dbfile="root:########@localhost/parafarmacie"
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://"+dbfile+"?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0")
```

all my columns that work with text are declared as Unicode, I googled for days but without any luck, someone could tell me where is my mistake?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you get your unicode objects from the database, before you output them, you need to encode them:

```
my_unicode_object.encode("utf-8")
```

What you are seeing now is the raw repr of the unicode object which shows you the code point (since it hasn't been converted to bytes yet) :-)

Comment: `\u20ac` is in fact the Unicode codepoint of the Euro symbol.  Your database logic is apparently fine.